# DynamoDB: Why I need access/secret keys while accessing it locally

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am using DynamoDB locally. Using aws-sdk in Node.js, If I do not use `AccessKey` and `secretAccessKey`

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update({
  region: 'us-east-2',
  endpoint: "http://localhost:8000"
});
```

I get error `"Missing credentials in config"`

If I use my AWS EC2 instance `AccessKey` and `secretAccessKey`, the error goes away

```
AWS.config.update({
  accessKeyId: 'myAccesskey',
  secretAccessKey: 'mySecretkey',
  region: 'us-east-2',
  endpoint: "http://localhost:8000"
});
```

But why is that? I am using the local DynamoDB. It shouldn't need my AWS credential. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

From [Setting Up DynamoDB Local (Downloadable Version)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBLocal.html):

> DynamoDB will use a single database file, instead of using separate files for each credential and region. If you specify `-sharedDb`, all DynamoDB clients will interact with the same set of tables regardless of their region and credential configuration.

It is likely that the credentials themselves are not validated, but are used to uniquely identify users to present different views depending upon the above option.